# Best way to power 30-90 LEDs on 3.5 OR 12v

Tags: arduino, led, led-driver, led-matrix

I have 6 3x10 blocks of LEDs (3 blocks red, 3 blocks white), all controlled individually.

```
  r r r r r r r r r r
+ r r r r r r r r r r -
  r r r r r r r r r r
```

(wired in parallel)

I'm controlling the blocks of LEDs using an Arduino MKRZERO.

I'm able to make 1 LED shine very bright per every output pin on the Arduino. However, I cannot make an entire block of lights shine very bright. They're actually very dim.

The I/O pins on the Arduino can only handle 3.5 volts.

If I by-pass the Arduino, I'm able to make a block of lights shine very bright.

At most I will have 3 blocks (90 LEDs total) shining, and at least 1 block (30 LEDs); except when it's off where obviously there would be no LEDs on.

The blocks will flash, only being on for no more than 1 second.

Everything needs to be powered by a 12v car charger (cig lighter port).

Currently I have an adapter that plugs into the car charger, and coverts to USB. I then took a USB cable and wired it to a voltage step down that goes to the Arduino. From the Arduino pins I have wires going to the light blocks.

The lights I'm using are 5mm clear straw hat red and white.
http://ledz.com/led.datasheet/412PWO4C.pdf
http://ledz.com/led.datasheet/412MR2C.pdf

Multiplexing
Where you can trick the brain into thinking all the lights are on. If I went this route, I would at most have 3 LEDs on at a time right? I've never seen this done with flashing blocks of LEDs, or this many... or really ever seen this.

Transistors
To my understanding I can put 12 volts to all the lights, and use transistors connected to the Arduino that would act as a switch for each block of lights.
One transistor per block of lights, right?

I'd like to go the easiest, and least expensive route.

Comment: What voltages *could* you have available for powering the LEDs?

Comment: The arduino site says the max voltage an IO pin can tolerate is 3.5v. Unless I'm misunderstanding this, I would say 3.5v is the max. I have a 5v source, that I'm stepping down to 3.5v.

Comment: When you have that many LEDs and your worry is about the max voltage rating of the IO pin of your microcontroller, then you're doing it wrong. You should have some sort of driver circuitry between the micro and your LEDs.

Comment: You are very likely going to need a separate power supply for the LEDs if you are using a small power supply for the Arduino. You can use a transistor as a switch for the LEDs - it uses a small current (from the Arduino) to drive a large current (flowing through the LEDs). [Turning on multiple leds with arduino using transistor](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/65996/36731).

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I'm powering everything from a car cig lighter, which is 12 volts, but USB cables only support 5v... right? Or is that USB ports?

Comment: @brhans - so would an led driver, like the MAX7219, work in this case?

Comment: quick note: I just ripped apart a USB cable and used that to power just the LEDS (not the arduino) and it worked perfectly. They were very bright.

Comment: Is it possible, yes. Anything is possible. Really need to know the LED

Comment: I'm using red and white straw hat leds. I bought them from walmart so I'm not sure I have a data sheet.

Current... ehhh idk. This is all new to me, so I'm not sure what half of this stuff means. I don't have resistors on them (though I'm sure I should).

If I power the lights straight from the 12volt outlet, would I need to reduce that before it gets to the LEDs? I assume that's a lot of power to be throwing at them.

Comment: @JaWapa If you power the LEDs from 12 V then you can have a few in series. How many depends on the voltage drop across each LED. And yes, you must use a resistor to limit the current through the LEDs, and you must calculate the correct value for the resistor or else they will burn out, probably faster than you can disconnect them. Have a good go at searching for the datasheets for the LEDs, and then edit your question to mention that it is for use in a car and the links to the datasheets.

Comment: updated to contain the info

Comment: Come on man, "how do I light up LEDs" has been asked a HUNDRED times on this site.

Comment: I've updated it again to hopefully explain what I'm after more.

Comment: @insta not the same because there are no GPIO's in that question

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need to do is have your LEDs in a parallel arrangement of series strings of LEDs. This will enable you to minimise the current (power dissipation = I<sup>2</sup>R) and take advantage of the maximum voltage availble to drive them.

Assume 14.4 V for a car outlet. Assume 18.5 mA for the current through an LED and a voltage drop of 2.0 V across a red LED (from the [datasheet](http://ledz.com/led.datasheet/412MR2C.pdf) and avoiding the maximum value for the current thus giving a bit of leeway on the voltage). Assume 0.2 V V<sub>CE</sub> across the transistor (from its [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/2N3904.pdf)). Calculate the required resistance for three LEDs and the transistor in series. Round it up to the next-highest easily-available resistor value.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f853PC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Repeat the part of the circuit with the LEDs and resistor in parallel. Calculate the total current.

Find the maximum output current of an Arduino pin and calculate R3 so that that maximum current is not reached - at this point you may find that the transistor does not have enough gain (q.v.). Consider using a Darlington transistor. Further research might lead you to using a logic-level-compatible MOSFET.

Note that a 2N3904 has a maximum collector-emitter current of 200 mA, so it is not really suitable or this (too close for comfort and will need a heatsink). Uh-oh. Choose a suitable transistor, check the V<sub>CE</sub> and re-calculate the resistor value.

Calculate the power dissipated (I<sup>2</sup>R) in the resistor to select an appropriate one. Insufficient power dissipation capability in any of the components may turn your flashing light bar into a "this vehicle is on fire" alert.

Now do it all again for the white LEDs.

None of the values are guaranteed to be correct in this answer.

Next, wait for someone to point out any glaring errors I have made :)

Comment: I have all 30 LEDs in one block in parallel, no resistors. There doesn't seem to be any problems there.

Should I change the way I have it?

Also, using this set up, the current would be going through the transistor, not the IO pin on the board... right?

Comment: @JaWapa Yes, you should change it. Otherwise you are likely to destroy the LEDs and/or the Arduino.

Comment: I was messing with the lights here, and it looks like 2 lights with a 100ohm resistor do not shine very bright.
`+led- +led- resistor`

Comment: @JaWapa It seems like you are replying too quickly to have fully comprehended what needs to be done. I suggest that you have a cup of tea and let your subconscious work on it for a little while :)

Comment: maybe so, this is kinda frustrating.