# Do I need diodes or resistor for PWM controlle RGB LED?

Tags: led, resistors, diodes, rgb, keyboard

I am planning to build a custom keyboard, using a pro micro and QMK firmware, and on my plan there would be an excess of 3 PWM pin. So I thought I can maybe put RGB leds on it on parallel. But the problem is how, it is just possible that I will just wired them on parallel, then it will work or I need to put some resistor or diodes on it? Also **IF** I want to control its brightness what should i need?

I will appreciate any advice will come, thanks.

BTW I don't have the parts for now so I cant test it. I am on the process of sourcing the part on where to buy for it.

I hope this is the right place to ask about this, please forgive I am very new in electronic, I just need some guidance.

Edit:

[Pro Micro](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/ATmega32U4-5V-16MHz-Module-New-Pro-Micro-for-arduino-with-2-row-pin-header-For-Leonardo/32708975582.html) Link to Aliexpress.

I am planning to put 7 individual LEDs or if possible I will put 15 or 25 LEDs so all the keys has LEDs

Comment: There is some essential data missing: A "pro micro" what? How many RGB LEDs, strip or individual LEDs?

Comment: @MatsK I added link to the "pro mico" basically it was a clone from [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640), for arduino controllers, but most of the custom and cheap keyboard use this cloned microcontroller. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to add the resistors for a single typical 20mA rgb led on a 5v or 3.3v microcontroller. Resistors are cheap.

For multiple leds or led strips, you need a more complicated circuit.

Comment: Hello I want it for multiple individual LED, about the resistors what kind of resistors should use?"sorry I am not so familiar with them, basically I am just learning by now", do you have a sample schematics for arranging the multiple LEDs? Thanks.

Comment: Example if I want to use this [LEDs](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/50pcs-Rectangular-LEDs-255-Diod-RGB-LED-Diffused-Cathode-Anode-Square-2-5-5mm-Red-Green/32655243116.html) from Aliexpress.

Comment: It also ok to me without controlling the LEDs brightness, as long its lights up.

Comment: @zer09 common anode or common cathode means you have to wire them all up in parallel, with a resistor for each color. Easiest is common anode, and a transistor or mosfet for each color.

Comment: @zer09 see this question for example schematic and setup https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65996/turning-on-multiple-leds-with-arduino-using-transistor

Comment: Thanks, I read the link you give, but still trying to understand it. BTW If I the source voltage is 3.3v and the led forward voltage is 3.3v, does 1 ohms resistor per color is enough? or I need more higher ohms on the resistor?